# What is this 2x2 part with one corner curved up?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, piece-usage

I recently came across this LEGO part:

[image: Part photo]

What part is this? What can it be used for?

Answer (score 8):

The part is [Plate Special 2 x 2 with Double Inverted Curve, 1 Stud (4190)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4190/plate-special-2-x-2-with-double-inverted-curve-1-stud/).

[image: Part render]

It was introduced in a few sets in 2023. It's original use was to provide an upward curve on roofs. This can be seen very easily in [Himeji Castle (21060)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/21060-1/himeji-castle/):

[image: Himeji Castle]

It can of course be used for many other things. Trivially, these parts can be tiled to create small peaks in a 4x4 area:

[image: 4x peak]

These parts are also compatible with some of the other recent inverted curved slope elements. For example, here it is next to [Brick Curved, Internal Double, 3 x 3 with 1/3 Inverted Cutout, Corner (73682)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/73682/brick-curved-internal-double-3-x-3-with-13-inverted-cutout-corner/):

[image: Profile comparison 3x3 Curved Slope Double 73682]

This is the same profile as [Brick Curved, 3 x 1 with 1/3 Inverted Cutout(70681)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/70681/brick-curved-3-x-1-with-13-inverted-cutout/):

[image: Profile comparison 1x3 Arch Inverted 70681]

This curve also aligns perfectly with the curve of the [telephone bow](https://rebrickable.com/parts/93273/slope-curved-4-x-1-double-with-no-studs/), assuming that is can be inverted:

[image: 93273 render]

Here's one way those parts can be used together:

[image: Telephone bow compatibility]

[image: Telephone bow front]

Because the telephone lines up with a pair of these, the [2x1 bow slope](https://rebrickable.com/parts/11477/slope-curved-2-x-1-no-studs-12-bow/) also lines up easily:

[image: 11477 Render]

The notched variant (29119/29120) of those slopes are also compatible:

[image: 29119]
[image: 29120]

In fact, those parts can be used to fill both sides of this part at once:

[image: Corner with 29119/29120]

There are plenty of ways to use this part, either by integrating with other slopes, or arranging it using SNOT techniques. For example, here's a quick window that I made to demonstrate how these can be combined to create a nearly circular outline:

[image: Window design]